# How to set Background Image for JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, background, jinternalframe

I try more script to set background in `JInternalFrame` but no one successfull. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, this is the same concept as setting the background image for a `JFrame`

### You Could

Create `JLabel`, set the image as the labels icon and set the label as the `JInternalFrame`'s content pane, making sure you set the layout manager for the label (or content pane after you changed it)

### You Could

Create a custom panel, that paints the image via the panels `paintComponent` method

This is good if you want to make the background resizable as the window is resized

Take a look at [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928for) an example

You would then, simply set this as the frame's content pane

Comment: Can you share the example script?

Comment: Did you 1- check the linked example; 2- check the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html); 3- Check the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html); 4- Search for examples of setting the background image of a JFrame?